# Showing UIView back in same frame after removeFromSuperView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am using an UIView as container for UIButton. When user opens keyboard, I am removing from superview and adding in to TextField AccessoryView for sticky button design.

```
[_buttonView removeFromSuperview];
[_usernameTextField setInputAccessoryView:_buttonView];
```

But after that I add view back the view show top of the screen. I Set its frame but, it is also not working.

```
_buttonView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 561, 320, 106);
[self.view addSubview:_buttonView];
```

So I know that, removeFromSubView method removes view from memory, so frame is not stored. If I don't removeFromSubView AccessoryView is not adding it because of parent child issue.

Comment: If you want same view again then hide and unhide view don't use `removeFromSubView`.

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre without removeFromSubView I can not add that view to InputAccessoryView

Comment: can you add screen shots to understand more.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so, when removing the `UIView` from its `superview` all of the constraints are removed as well. You would need to add the constraints again to have it appear in the desired location.

Comment: I am not using Auto Layout. Whatever, I guess I can not fix it